# Advert as form submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

Is it possible to make an ad on a page the submit button to a form? I wanted to give users the option to wait a length of time and then click a button or if they clicked an ad it would instantly submit the form.

The ads I am using are given as an `iframe`. I've tried placing a transparent `div` over top the ad. Javascript can detect that, but not the iframe due to cross site scripting I have learned.

Comment: So what is wrong with using the transparent div?

Comment: I think that would be a great way to implement it, but I could not figure it out. I'm not as versed with javascript as I am with other languages.

Comment: Javascript would detect clicking the `div`, but the ad would not open. I thought about simulating a double click after first removing the `div`. I wasn't sure how to do that of if even possible.